# When looping, how does .iter() differ from a reference (&)?

Tags: loops, reference, rust

While playing with Rust, I discovered that you can loop over `Vec`s and `HashMap`s (and probably others) by reference, instead of using `.iter()`.

```
let xs = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for x in &xs {
    println!("x == {}", x);
}
```

The `.iter()` function seems to have the same behavior.

```
let xs = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for x in xs.iter() {
    println!("x == {}", x);
}
```

Are both methods of looping over a collection functionally identical, or are there subtle differences between how the two behave? I notice that `.iter()` seems to be the universally preferred approach in examples that I've found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are both methods of looping over a collection functionally identical

Yes, they are identical.

[The implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&Vec<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.2.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1534-L1542):

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

[The implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&HashMap<K, V, S>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.2.0/src/libstd/collections/hash/map.rs#L1351-L1361):

```
impl<'a, K, V, S> IntoIterator for &'a HashMap<K, V, S>
    where K: Eq + Hash, S: HashState
{
    type Item = (&'a K, &'a V);
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, K, V>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, K, V> {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

Note that both just call `iter()`.

> I notice that .iter() seems to be the universally preferred approach in examples that I've found.

I use `collection.iter()` whenever I want to use an iterator adapter, and I use `&collection` whenever I want to just iterate directly on the collection.

Comment: Honestly surprised there isn't some very subtle and unexpected 'gotcha' difference. Also, wow, do you just have _all_ the Rust answers? +1.

Comment: @KChaloux Absolutely not all the answers. Just a good amount of time and almost one year of reading lots of good questions and answers. Note that I'm one of the top question **askers** as well. ^_^